# Swift - Use UITextField as search for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a UITextField:

```
@IBOutlet weak var vendorTextField: UITextField!
```

and I am using the delegate method textFieldShouldBeginEditing to bring up a table view to display search results for whatever is typed into UITextField:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        let searchViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchController") as! SearchController
        
        searchViewController.searchText = textField.text!
        
        let vc = searchViewController

        addChild(vc)
        
        vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.vendorTextField.bounds.width, height: 300)
        
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
        
        vc.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        return true
    }
```

The one problem I am facing is trying to get the UITableView to appear right below the UITextField and is there away to have it animate down when it appears?

Answer (score 0):

Basic steps to position the loaded table view below your text field:

```
vc.view.frame = vendorTextField.frame
vc.view.frame.origin.y += vendorTextField.frame.height
vc.view.frame.size.height = 300
```

If you want to animate it into view - so it "slides down" from the text field"

- create an empty, clear `UIView` as a "holder"
- set the frame of that holder view as above
- add the loaded table view as a subview of the holder view
- set its frame to the bounds of the holder view
- set its frame's `.origin.y` to `-holderView.frame.height`
- animate `.origin.y` to Zero

Don't forget to set `.clipsToBounds = true` on the holder view so we don't see the table view while it is "above" the frame.

So, step one, add the holder view (outlined in red):

[image]

add the table view as a subview of the holder view, positioned above its top (showing as translucent here):

[image]

animate the table view into position:

[image]

Here's how it looks (with slowed-down animation):

[image]

and the code:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    
    // return false if we can't load the Search Controller
    guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchController") as? SearchController else { return false }

    let str = textField.text ?? "No search text yet"
    vc.searchText = str
    
    addChild(vc)
    
    // we should use auto-layout, but for a quick example...
    
    // let's create an empty view to hold the tableView
    let holderView = UIView()
    
    // position it directly under the text field, same width and x-position
    //  a little short-cut: start with the same frame, then adjust the Y and Height
    holderView.frame = vendorTextField.frame
    holderView.frame.origin.y += vendorTextField.frame.height
    holderView.frame.size.height = 300
    
    // clip to bounds, so we can animate the table view into view
    holderView.clipsToBounds = true
    
    // table view frame same as holder view bounds
    vc.view.frame = holderView.bounds
    
    // now, move it up above the frame of the holder view
    vc.view.frame.origin.y = -holderView.frame.size.height
    
    // add the tableView to the holder view
    holderView.addSubview(vc.view)
    
    // add the holder view to the view
    view.addSubview(holderView)
    
    vc.didMove(toParent: self)
    
    // animate it into view
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        vc.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    })
    
    return true
}
```